# Proper CSV export from SQL Server

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008, csv, weka

I have a table in SQL Management Studio I want to export as a CSV and afterwards import it into WEKA.
I queried all data from the table, selected it, then right-clicked and chose "Save results as"->CSV.
When I try to import this CSV into WEKA, I get the following error message:

```
File <path> not recognized as an 'CSV data files' here.
Reason:
wrong number of values. READ 27, expected 26, read Token[EOL], line 1023
```

I assume, I need to escape a String at line 1023, but what if another 100... errors will follow?

Is there any way to automatically escape all characters to get a proper CSV file, without post-processing?

Comment: So, basically, what you want is a "proper" CSV-export from SQL-Server Management with all critical strings properly escaped, yes? The import into WEKA is then really quite straightforward.

Comment: @cars10: You are right, I changed the title.

Comment: Have you looked into SSIS? Assuming WEKA has some sort of ODBC/OLE DB connection, you could handle all this in a package.  This would also facilitate future runs of the same export/import process.

Comment: what about BCP, or import/export wizard?

Comment: TTeeple's hint seems very appropriate! But if you want to go the CSV way you should make sure that you select the separator option and a text delimiter like `"` on the dialog-page where the flatfile target is specified. Two dialog pages further on you can then define the actual separator symbol (e.g. comma or semicolon).

Comment: Sorry, just noticed in a little export test, that the SSMS export wizard does *not* take care of any line breaks within exported strings! These will probably be the cause of your problem ...

Comment: If this is a one-off, I would use the export wizard.